# Community question with reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, community-wiki

From what I understand, the community wiki doesn't generate reputation points. But I think a question turned into a wiki still does. I have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278026//1279123#1279123) on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278026) that has been turned into a wiki a while ago and I'm still earning rep.

Not that I don't want to earn that rep ;) but I don't think this is how it was supposed to be implemented.

Comment: Do you have a link to said post?

Comment: @Juan, I would guess this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278026

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a question starts as CW, all answers to that question are CW, the answerer has no choice. If a question is switched after being asked to CW, this does not force all answers to CW. My guess is you're referring to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278026/are-there-any-good-metaphors-for-explaining-project-complexity-to-a-non-programme/1279123#1279123) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278026). While the question is now CW, your answer is not, and therefore you can still receive reputation from voting.

> **Editor's note:** The system has since been changed to automatically convert all answers to community wiki if and when the question gets converted, making this situation less likely. This situation can still happen in some cases, such as conversions before the change as well as merged posts (specifically, a non-CW question with answers being merged into a CW question).

Comment: I was indeed referring to that question. I just didn't feel like free publicity for my answer ;)
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A question can become wiki without changing the answers.

If the poster manually changes the question to CW or edit threshold is reached, then your answer won't change, but all of the new answers posted will be CW.

If a question gets auto CWed by >30 (different number for different sites) answers everything associated to the post becomes CW.

Comment: Why did you <strike> that last bit out? It's correct, as long as you also note that the 30-answer auto-CW threshold doesn't apply to questions which are already CW.

Comment: The auto CW threshold is different on different sites.

Comment: Who visits other sites? ...Oh, *those* other sites. Yeah.

Comment: I struck it out because I added an answer to the question in question (ha) and it didn't auto CW all of the answers.